# No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, php-7, elasticsearch-plugin

I installed elasticsearch [with the help of this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html) .

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(["localhost:9200"])->build();  
$response = ''; 
try{
    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'id' => 'my_id',
        'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
    ]; 
    $response = $client->indices()->create($params);        
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
}
print_r($response);
die('End : Elastic Search');
```

It returns me **No alive nodes found in your cluster**.
When I change the port to 80

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(["localhost:80"])->build();
```

it gave me below error.

**Method Not Allowed. The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /my_index.**

Comment: can you post your elasticsearch.yml files on the elastic server?

Comment: why are you shuffling the elastic port between 80 and 9200, by default elastic server will listen to 9200 port only if you explicitly change that to 80. i may take a look at your elasticsearch.yml file to see if you have enabled remote access for port 9200 or other stuff

Comment: @user3775217 I could find elasticsearch.yml file in **/etc/elasticsearch** directory. All the contents in that file are commented.

Comment: hmm, that means your elastic server is listening at default port 9200

Comment: how did you installed elasticsearch? the link you shared in your post regarding elasticsearch is to install elasticsearch php client not elasticsearch server.

Answer (score 2):

check if your network is watching the ip of elastic service, if you are using docker, before composing container, check inside your web app server over shell if you are watching the ip of service and adding the ip in the .env file and execute again the docker compose.
in another cases check if you vps o development environment is pinging o watching the ip of elastic service

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to restart the `elasticsearch` daemon? Like:

```
systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

Then, check if it's running:

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
```

If not, check the log files for any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Elasticsearch server in docker as the doc, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

But it uses a different network (networks: - esnet) with other services and it cannot talk to the application network. After remove the networks setting and it works well.

Answer (score -1):

You mixed between index and document creation, first you need to create the index (like table in regular relational database), and then insert now document

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$indexParams = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 5,
            'number_of_replicas' => 1
        ]
    ]
];

$docParams = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
];    

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(["localhost:9200"])->build();  
$response = ''; 
try {
    /* Create the index */
    $response = $client->indices()->create($indexParams);
    print_r($response);

    /* put doc in the index */
    $response = $client->index($docParams);
    print_r($response);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
}
die('End : Elastic Search');
```

Comment: Even the above code returned me the same error. **Exception : No alive nodes found in your clusterEnd : Elastic Search**

Comment: Try to connect via port 80

Comment: Now I got the other error. **Method Not Allowed.
The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /my_index.**

Answer (score -1):

set breackpoint on vendor\guzzlehttp\ringphp\src\Client\CurlHandler.php on method CurlHandler::_invokeAsArray and see `$response`
also use

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts([['host' =>self::$CONF['elasticSearchHost'],'port' => '80','scheme'=>'http']])->build();
```